I'm looking for a way to return multiple values in an array formula on Google Sheets - haven't been able to find a solution
Scenario: I have a roster of dog owners who have had dogs involved in various training classes. I have a list of the dogs and their respective classes, and I have a list of the owners. I want to populate a column on the owner list with only the dogs that are currently involved in the "basic obedience" class.
The problem I cannot solve is when one owner has multiple dogs. I have two scenarios set up. One owner has two dogs, but only one is in "basic obedience," so that's the only one I want returned. The other owner has two dogs, both in "basic obedience," so I would want them both returned. I don't care if they're in the same cell, or different cells on the same line, as long as they're both displayed.
I have found multiple ways that get me almost to the result I need. I've included three of them on the linked sheet.

Column D - this column has the result I want, but not in an array
formula. I want an array formula so I don't have to copy/paste every
time I add a new row.
Column E - this is the working formula from
column D, but when I put it into an array formula it stops working.
Column F - this is the closest I was able to get using an array
formula with vlookups, but I don't know if it's possible to get it to
return multiple values.

I've seen some Q&As that reference a query function, and honestly that's a little over-engineering this sheet based on what it will be used for. If that's my only option, I'll probably just stick with my first solution and go with the copy/paste.
Thanks for your help!
Link to Google Sheet

You can use BYROW to apply your working formula to the whole array. Look at column G:
=BYROW(A3:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="",,JOIN(char(10),IFNA(filter(I:I,each=H:H,M:M="Basic Obedience"))))))


Also a good advice is to put your formula in the header, like this in row 2:
=VSTACK("Name of the Header",BYROW(A3:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="",,JOIN(char(10),IFNA(filter(I:I,each=H:H,M:M="Basic Obedience")))))))


Made some suggested edits. Roll back if you disapprove. FYI the IF function is unnecessary. Empty each will similarly fail the FILTER as a populated value that doesn't meet all conditions. Maybe performance improvement over huge data set. =BYROW(A3:A,LAMBDA(each,JOIN(char(10),ifna(filter(I:I,H:H=each,M:M="Basic Obedience")))))

I would use the following formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(let(dogs,$J$3:$J$24,
filters,(A3=$I$3:$I$24)*($N$3:$N$24="Basic Obedience"),
filteredDogs,filter(dogs,filters),
res,if(ISERROR(filteredDogs),"",filteredDogs),
join(CHAR(10),res)))

First of all, I love the LET function, because you can break up the formula into multiple steps, and in some situtations increases efficiency (e.g. if you reference the same range multiple times).
ARRAYFORMULA forces using array formulas, so that's necessary in this case.
filters,(A3=$I$3:$I$24)*($N$3:$N$24="Basic Obedience"),
This line is kinda the real magic here. You have two criteria - the name of the owner (A3=$I$3:$I$24), and the course in which the dog is enrolled ($N$3:$N$24="Basic Obedience"). Each of these returns an array of boolean values (TRUE or FALSE). When you multiply them together, they convert to 0's and 1's, which returns an array of 0's and 1's. This is your filter. More critera can be added if needed, so this is a very useful tool to use if you want to filter by several sets of criteria.
filteredDogs,filter(dogs,filters),
Now we actually filter the data. This is pretty standard, and we're setting it equal to the variable filteredDogs. You will notice that the filteredDogs variable is used twice in the following line, so using LET saves us a bit here. It can save a lto more in other applications, I assure you.
res,if(ISERROR(filteredDogs),"",filteredDogs),
Now, the filter will result in #N/A errors if the owner doesn't have a dog matching the criteria, so we simply replace an error with empty quotes.
join(CHAR(10),res)))
Finally, we use CHAR(10), which is a newline character, as a delimiter to join the results of the array, if there are more than one.
If you wish to use an additional column instead, you could replace the join function with transpose:
transpose(res)
This will just change the arrays from a vertical array to a horizontal array.
